# Matrix printing in checkerboard method with c++ MPI

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a problem. I am currently working on an exercise where i need to print a matrix in such a way: a matrix is split between processors so that is satisfies the equation n/sqrt(p) = b, where n is the matrix size n x n, p is the processor count and b is the block size b x b. The way that the processors split the matrix is that each processors takes a block of size b x b and then, without sharing the inner information of the blocks, the processors should print out the matrix. For example: the goal matrix is 4x4 matrix and there are 4 processors, so the block that each processor takes is 2 x 2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void gen_b(vector< vector<int> > &block, int num, int rank) {
    // Fill the block with the specified value
    int b_size = block.size();
    int n_num = num + rank;
    for (int i = 0; i < b_size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b_size; j++)
        {
            block[i][j] = n_num;
        }
    }
}
void b_c_dist(vector< vector<int> > &block, int b_size, int rank, int size)
{
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    //for loop that stops all ranks at a barrier, then the rank that meets the criterion prints, others wait at another barrier
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            //makes all other processors wait at this point until all processors are finished with their previous work
            MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            if (i == rank)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < b_size; k++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < b_size; j++)
                    {
                        cout << block[k][j] << " ";
                    }
                }
                
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int m_size = atoi(argv[2]);
    int b_size = m_size / sqrt(size);
    //errors for wrong command liine
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        cerr << "Usage: mpiexec -n <processor count> <executable> <number to fill> <matrix size>" << endl;
        MPI_Finalize();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int size_n = static_cast<int>(sqrt(size));
    if(m_size % size_n != 0)
    {
        cerr << "The processor count squared has to satisfy m = n/sqrt(p) " << endl;
        MPI_Finalize();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else if(size_n * size_n != size)
    {
        cerr << "The processor count squared has to satisfy m = n/sqrt(p) " << endl;
        MPI_Finalize();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    int num = atoi(argv[1]);
    
    vector< vector<int> > block(b_size, vector<int>(b_size, 0));
    //fills values
    gen_b(block, num, rank);
    //prints
    b_c_dist(block, b_size, rank, size);

    MPI_Finalize();
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code. So firstly the "gen_b" function generates the block that is filled a number that is given in the command line, in this case let's take 1. Rank 0 is filled with 1s, rank 1 is filled with 2s, rank 2 with 3s and so on. Then the b_c_dist should print out the blocks in the checkerboard method so that the final matrix would be:
1 1 2 2
1 1 2 2
3 3 4 4
3 3 4 4
The "rank == i" part is a primitive way of printing the matrices in order from rank 0.
Currently I have achieved that the matrix would be printed like this:
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
However, this is the part that i am stuck in. After a lot of tries I am unable to achieve the wanted checkerboard method and I have no idea how to write the algorith, so that it would print the numbers in blocks.

My idea of approach is that the processors would print in lines - rank 0 prints its first line, then rank 1, then rank 0 prints its second line, then the same with rank 1. Afterwards it switches to rank 2 and 3(i am still talking about the situation if the final matrix is 4x4 and there are 4 processors). Does anybody have an idea how should I alter the code in b_c_dist to achieve the wanted printing method?
I understand that my code is not perfect, but I would just like some suggestions for the algorithm :)

Comment: It is not possible to synchronize IO from parallel processes. Gather the matrix to one process and then print there.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout i fully understand that. However, i managed to print the numbers in an order in lines (i explained above), so i would think it is  possible to also achieve the “block printing”. I just do not know how to alter the inner printing algorithm to get that. What i want to say is i have read that it is impossible to fully synchronise IO, but maybe there is a partial solution to this problem. Moreover it is a university exercise, so i would believe there is a solution.

Comment: Maybe if you use `cerr`, which does not buffer.

Comment: Have rank `0` print all the matrix. The easiest way is to "gather" the matrix on rank `0` and then print it, but this has the highest memory overhead. You can also send chunks of the matrix at a time, just enough so rank `0` can print it. Or you can dump you matrix into a file with MPI-IO and then have rank `0` open that file and print the matrix.